# Show input value in title

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to show input value in plot title, my codes as below but it does not work

```
ma1 = input.int(5, 'MA 1', minval=1)

plot(ta.sma(source_ma, ma1), linewidth=1, color=color.new(#d1d4dc, 0), title='MA 1' + str.tostring(ma1))
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution, but there is an alternative for accomplishing what you want - you'll have to draw your own lines.

For example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", max_lines_count=500)

ma1 = input.int(5, 'MA 1', minval=1)
sma = ta.sma(close, ma1)

line.new(x1=bar_index[1], y1=sma[1], x2=bar_index, y2=sma)

if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    label.new(bar_index, na, text='MA 1' + str.tostring(ma1), color=color.new(#d1d4dc, 0), style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

There are some limitations as mentioned in the [documents](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#line-and-box-styles).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

The `title` argument of `plot()` expects a `const string`, which means its value must be known at compile time which is not the case here.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for your answer. Can you give me an alternative example for achieving this issue?

Comment: There isn't a way to accomplish that.